# ClassCastException when casting result of DecimalFormat.parse() when decimal is 0

Tags: java, parsing, number-formatting, classcastexception, decimalformat

I'm using `DecimalFormat` to deal with number formats from different locales. My `DecimalFormat` variable is declared as follows:

```
NumberFormat m_nf;
DecimalFormat m_df;

if (strCountry.equals("IT") || strCountry.equals("ES"))
    locale = java.util.Locale.ITALIAN;
else
    locale = java.util.Locale.ENGLISH;

m_nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale);

m_nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);

m_df = (DecimalFormat) m_nf;
m_df.applyPattern(".0");
```

I'm then obtaining a value from my method `getLowerLimit()`  and formatting it as a string. This could either be something like "2.1" (in US format) or "2,1" in Italian format. The value is then stored as a `Double` using `DecimalFormat.parse()`.

```
try {
    String strValue = m_df.format(getLowerLimit());
    Double nValue = (Double) m_df.parse(strValue);
} catch (ParseException | ClassCastException e) {
    ErrorDialogGenerator.showErrorDialog(ExceptionConstants.LOWER_LIMIT, e);
    System.exit(1);
}
```

This code is working OK for me EXCEPT when the decimal of the number is 0. For example it works when the value is "2.1" but not when it is "2.0". That is when it throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

Why won't it work when the decimal is a 0? How do I rectify this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `NumberFormat.parse()`returns a `Number`, it can return any concrete `Number` implementation, such as `Integer` or `Float`, for example.
Casting it to `Double` you make an assumption that it will return `Double`, but it might prove wrong in many cases (as you've witnessed).

If you wish to get result as `Double`, you should go with `Number.doubleValue()` as such:

```
Double nValue = m_df.parse(strValue).doubleValue();
```

Comment: Thanks, that was all that was needed!